# Why do I get "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax..."? (PDO-PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I know this question has been asked many times but from the many ones I looked at it seems they always used a mysql reserved keyword as a table or column name or actually have a syntax error here or there, but I don't think I have either so I'd appreciate some help figuring out why I get this. Here's the function that causes the error:

```
public function user_exists($db, $username) {
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $username);

    try {
        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

        if($rows == 1) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Then when it's called with, say, 'anything' as its $username parameter, here's the full error I get:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your  SQLsyntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right  syntax to use near ''users' WHERE 'username'= anything' at line 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backticks to escape table or column names, not quotes.

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks:

change

```
"SELECT COUNT('id') FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = ?"
```

to

```
"SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?"
```